# WebBrowser Control shared cookie - maybe

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

When a popup is loaded in Internet Explorer the user is often prompted to re-login.  Once the user has logged in everything works fine.  The `WebBrowser` Control definitely appears to set a cookie. I can see it in IECookiesView (program).    The caveat is that they both (the WebBrowser and IE) seem to share the same cookie... It just seems to be ignored by Internet Explorer until the user logs in.

Is this possible?  How can I stop the user having to re-login?

Comment: Are you sure the domain is the same?

Comment: Yep, I've tested this so many times and its driving me mad.  I clear all the cookies and  I watch it appear when I open the WebBrowser Control and than I watch its upadate time change with the popup.  The cookie contents looks exactly the same.  I'm baffled.

Comment: Also, the requirement to re-login is only on some pcs.  I have checked the security settings and found nothing special.

Comment: I hate the WebBrowser control... This is going to sound weird, but have you tried loading the page twice before opening the pop-up (in the web browser control)?

Comment: I hate the webBrowser control too.  The refresh idea didnt work.  But I think I might have made a mistake,  I think I can only see the cookie for the control, not the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by including my domain as a "Trusted Site" in Internet Options